# How the α value is calculated in katz backoff language model?

Tags: statistics, nlp, probability, n-gram

Im currently working on the implementation for katz backoff smoothing language model. i have some confusion about the recursive backoff and α calculation lower order models. Suppose the katz model for trigram is given as

P<sub>katz</sub>(w<sub>i</sub>|w<sub>i-2</sub>w<sub>i-1</sub>)= P(w<sub>i</sub>|w<sub>i-2</sub>w<sub>i-1</sub>), if C(w<sub>i-2</sub>w<sub>i-1</sub>w<sub>i</sub>) > 0 
                           or  α<sub>1</sub>P(w<sub>i</sub>|w<sub>i-1</sub>), if C(w<sub>i-2</sub>w<sub>i-1</sub>w<sub>i</sub>) = 0 and C(w<sub>i-1</sub>w<sub>i</sub>) > 0
                            or  α<sub>2</sub>P(w<sub>i</sub>), otherwise

I also know that α1 for bigram case is calculated from the discounts found from trigram model but my confusion is how it calculates the α2 for lower order unigram. Does it use the discounts from the trigram model or it uses discounts from bigram model if both trigram and bigram case has zero evidence?

Comment: It's either using a fixed discount across all levels of ngram, or using specific discount for each level. I don't know the exact answer, but am pretty sure you can find it in Goodman and Chen paper (page 6): http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~yogo/courses/mt2013/papers/chen-goodman-99.pdf

Comment: Dear  user3639557, thanks a lot for your suggestions.  I have read the chen and goodman paper but i am still confused about the recursive implementation of katz backoff  and the calculation  of α2 parameter. i need specific solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the alpha is based on the "missing probability mass". The alpha is to make sure the sum of the probability of ngram models including back-off equals to 1.

So for your question, if you have discount in bigram, there will be some missing probabiliies. I think you need use 1 - sum of trigram probabilities - alpha * sum of the bigram probabilities to find the next alpha for unigram.